# JSF2 - ui:repeat, 1st commandLink doesn't work but others do

Tags: jsf-2, commandlink, uirepeat

I have a ui:repeat loop to perfom some paging:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" style="height: 25px;text-align: right" id="Prod-printed-paging">
  <ui:repeat value="#{upBean.pagesProdPrinted}"
     id="Prod-printed-page-loop"
     var="cppage" varStatus="cpstatus" >
     <h:panelGroup rendered="#{cpstatus.first and not (upBean.pageProdPrinted == '1')}">
        <h:commandLink id="previous" style="color: #390">#{appMsg.previous}
           <f:ajax listener="#{upBean.previousPageProdPrinted}"
              event="click"
              render=":form-myProd:get-printed-Prod :form-myProd:Prod-printed-paging"/>
        </h:commandLink> |
     </h:panelGroup>
     <h:panelGroup rendered="#{upBean.pageProdPrinted eq cppage}">
        <h:panelGroup style="font-weight: bold">#{cppage}</h:panelGroup>
     </h:panelGroup>
     <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not (upBean.pageProdPrinted eq cppage)}">
        <h:commandLink>
           <h:panelGroup>#{cppage}</h:panelGroup>
           <f:ajax listener="#{upBean.goToPagePrinted(cppage)}"
              event="click"
              render=":form-myProd:get-printed-Prod :form-myProd:Prod-printed-paging"/>
        </h:commandLink>
     </h:panelGroup>
     <h:panelGroup rendered="#{cpstatus.last and not (upBean.pageProdPrinted == upBean.nbPageProdPrinted)}">
      | <h:commandLink id="next" style="color: #390">#{appMsg.next}
           <f:ajax listener="#{upBean.nextPageProdPrinted}"
              event="click"
              render=":form-myProd:get-printed-Prod :form-myProd:Prod-printed-paging"/>
         </h:commandLink>
     </h:panelGroup>
   </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This displays fine like this (in the case we are on a page > page n. 1):

Previous | 1 2 3 4 | next

All links are working well (firing the ManagedBean action) but the "Previous: link. Clicking "Previous" seems to do something:
- I see it sends a partial-request (from firebug Console tab) but breakpoint at the "previousPageProdPrinted" doesn't get caught.

I have a h:form, not nested in another one. Is there anything I can do to track this issue?

Environment:
- Glassfish 3.1
- Mojarra  2.1.3 (FCS b02)

Thank you for reading,
JSC